# Lie algebra of Spin Group

Tags: clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

In Peskin's QFT textbook, eq.(3.23):
\begin{equation}
S^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]
\end{equation}
gives a Lie algebra representations of Lorentz group or more generally $SO(p,q)$, but author didn't mention how to deduce it. It is also known that the double cover of $SO(p,q)$ is spin group $Spin(p,q)$ whose Lie algebra is the same as that of $SO(p,q)$. My question is, does eq.(3.23) in the book actually form the Lie algebra representation of $Spin(p,q)$? If so, can one provide some details about it, or some references which mention the above result?

Comment: It should, yes. In [geometric algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra) terminology $[\gamma^\mu, \gamma_\nu] = 2\gamma^\mu\wedge\gamma^\nu$ where $\wedge$ is the [exterior product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), where here the gammas are to be thought of as vectors in the algebra $Cl_{1,3}(\mathbb R)$. These are bivectors, and the bivectors together with the commutator represent the Lie algebra for the associated spin group $Spin(1,3)$. See Chapter 11.3 in *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* (2003) by Chris Doran and Anthony Lasenby.

Comment: I am not sure how this interacts with the complexification $Cl_{1,3}(\mathbb C)$, however.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Thank you for pointing out the reference！